# iPhone Image Rotate when user drags touch?

Tags: iphone, sdk

im trying to create a circle image (static) and make it rotate when the user drags the image either clockwise or counter clockwise also keep its speed. i seen these effects in alot of apps in the app store. would anyone have a tutorial out to work with or a small sample?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
CGFloat Angle=(((int)slider.value*M_PI)/180);
transform=CGAffineTransformScale(transform,appdel.objCustomImageView.scale,appdel.objCustomImageView.scale);

transform= CGAffineTransformRotate(transform,Angle);

appdel.objCustomImageView.transform = transform;
```

Comment: what to do if theres no slider. Its just an image and I can detect the touch on it. and also what must be the type and initial value of transform?

Comment: If you need to rotate based on touch, you need to calculate line from 2 different view points while you first touch. Then as you are moving the other finger you need to calculate the other line and find Angle between these lines.